# Android captive portal check

Tags: android, linux, nginx

We have configured our own captive portal on a Linux box (nginx + iptables + hostapd). So now we are testing this.

Nginx is configured so that any request from mobile clients (actually not 127.0.0.1) will be redirected to a specific page. No internet access or login etc. Only specified page for all request per 80 port.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp ! -d 192.168.198.1 --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 80
```

And nginx

```
if ($remote_addr != 127.0.0.1)
set $mobile_rewrite perform; }

if ($request_uri !~* "/designer/upload.php")
set $url A; }

if ($mobile_rewrite = "perform") {
set $url "${url}B"; }

if ($request_uri !~* (\.js|\.css|\.gif|\.png|php)$) {
set $url "${url}C"; }

if ($request_uri !~* "/designer/ajax.php*") {
set $url "${url}D"; }

if ($url = "ABCD") {
rewrite ^(.*)$ /designer/upload.php redirect; }
```

Ajax.php and js|css|gif|png|php need for upload tool.

So now when the hotspot is started and connected to wifi from iPhone it's working like a charm. Browser opening window and redirected to upload tool.

If I try to do same with Android Samsung TAB3 Android 4.1.2 no browser window popup, we need to manually open any page. Only after these steps, the upload page will be displayed.

Some logs from nginx

```
192.168.198.11 - - [11/Jun/2014:08:19:38 +0000] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.2; SM-T210 Build/JZO54K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.141 Safari/537.36"
192.168.198.11 - - [11/Jun/2014:08:19:38 +0000] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.2; SM-T210 Build/JZO54K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.141 Safari/537.36"
192.168.198.11 - - [11/Jun/2014:08:19:38 +0000] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.2; SM-T210 Build/JZO54K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.141 Safari/537.36"
192.168.198.11 - - [11/Jun/2014:08:19:38 +0000] "HEAD /designer/upload.php HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.2; SM-T210 Build/JZO54K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.141 Safari/537.36"
192.168.198.11 - - [11/Jun/2014:08:19:38 +0000] "HEAD /designer/upload.php HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.2; SM-T210 Build/JZO54K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.141 Safari/537.36"
192.168.198.11 - - [11/Jun/2014:08:19:38 +0000] "HEAD /designer/upload.php HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.2; SM-T210 Build/JZO54K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.141 Safari/537.36"
192.168.198.11 - - [11/Jun/2014:08:19:39 +0000] "GET /generate_204 HTTP/1.1" 302 160 "-" "Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; SM-T210 Build/JZO54K)"
192.168.198.11 - - [11/Jun/2014:08:19:53 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 160 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.2; SM-T210 Build/JZO54K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.141 Safari/537.36"
192.168.198.11 - - [11/Jun/2014:08:19:53 +0000] "GET /designer/upload.php HTTP/1.1" 200 843 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.2; SM-T210 Build/JZO54K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.141 Safari/537.36"
```

So in logs I see that page /generate_204 wasn't first that has been opened. iPhone checking first successs.html by wispr and appeared popups. But Android not doing this.

So do we have any chance to get android working like iPhone?

Comment: Hello. Did you solve the problem? I have the same with captive portal on Mikrotik. I can see requests from Windows or iOS when connecting to hotspot, but not from Android.

Comment: Hello, nope, problem not resolved and we still have no solution.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to an old question but I experienced a very similar problem.

Had a Linux box with no Internet connection running nginx, wpa_supplicant in ap mode (mode=2), iptables and dnsmasq.

Iphones were automatically detecting and displaying Captive Portal immediately after connecting to the box's WiFi AP. However, Samsung phones running Android 4/5 couldn't do the same.

After some investigation, I thought **Android was expecting *clients3.google.com* to resolve to a public IP address, i.e., outside the class A, B, C private IP address ranges.**

So I did the following:

1) Configured dnsmasq to resolve all DNS requests arriving on wlan0 port to a randomly chosen public IP address (say A.B.C.D). So in /etc/dnsmasq.conf, set:

```
address=/#/A.B.C.D
```

2) Created a couple of iptables rules to translate destination IP address of all HTTP packets arriving on wlan0 port to the interface's IP address 192.168.1.1:

```
iptables -t nat -L PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp -dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.1
iptables -t nat -L POSTROUTING -i wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

And then, Android phones were automatically detecting and displaying the captive portal in a browser popup.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does this work in a Samsung phone for sure? Their CNA is different from other Android phones like Nexus or Pixel.